# SQL: Utilizar array de números em where sql

Tags: sql, dinâmico

Eu tenho uma base de dados que precisa do retorno de dados para a geração de um gráfico, no entanto, alguns registros deverão ser desconsiderados na consulta. Realizei diversas pesquisas e identifiquei que uma das formas possíveis seria declarar um array de números inteiros e usar o conteúdo deste array, dinamicamente, na condição onde ficando algo como:

```
select * from table where id <> conteudo_array
```

Por exemplo:

```
Tabela Frutas:
ID | NOME
1  | AMORA
2  | MAMÃO
3  | BANANA
4  | PÊSSEGO
5  | BANANA
6  | PERA
```

conteudo_array = [1, 5, 2]

O retorno deverá ser:

```
ID | NOME
3  | BANANA
4  | PÊSSEGO
6  | PERA
```

Como faço? Tentei recriar algumas soluções presentes no próprio stack, que usavam strings, mas sem sucesso. Grata <3

PS.: estou tentando executar esse sql no metabase

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: não sei se entendi direto sua pergunta mais se vc quer que apareça só determinados campos é so usar o select seguido dos campos q deseja.
select nome, email, fone from clientes;

Comment: `select * from table where id not in (1, 5, 2)`.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
$produtos = [
1  => AMORA,
2  => MAMÃO,
3  => BANANA,
4  => PÊSSEGO,
5  => BANANA,
6  => PERA
];

select * from table where id not in (1, 5, 2);
```

> testei aqui e deu certo

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

ok, agora entendi sua pergunta, vc pode criar um form com um input com os nomes q vc queira que apareça. por exemplo:

selecione a fruta:

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Famora" name="amora" checked>
  <label>Amora</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Fmamao" name="mamao" checked>
  <label>mamão</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Fbanana" name="banana" checked>
  <label>Banana</label>
</div>
```

e no selec ele apresentar os campos selecionado:

```
select Famora, Fbanana from table;
```

Comment: A questão é que eu não trabalho no front, apenas no back-end, eu tenho os registros que devem ser desconsiderados na consulta, gostaria de saber como declarar um array com esses ids dos registros pra utilizá-los como valores a não serem impressos, pra manter o código organizado. Consegui com a resposta do @Benilson mas gostaria de popular um array, com os ids, e colocar a referencia dele após o 'not in' mas não estou conseguindo declarar. Nem com o Declare array....

Comment: Mas, de qualquer forma, obrigada pela ajuda <3

Comment: algo como: declare array_id = (1, 5, 2); select * from frutas where id not in array_id;

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).